# Level editor in BGE

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I want to make a level editor where objects can be added on a grid kind of like minecraft when you place down I cube.
Here is the code.

```
from bge import logic as l 
from bge import events
from mathutils import Vector

c = l.getCurrentController()
o = c.owner

scn = l.getCurrentScene()
obj = scn.objects

mouse = l.mouse
lm = l.KX_INPUT_JUST_RELEASED  == mouse.events[events.LEFTMOUSE]

sens = c.sensors

ray = sens['Ray']
hitobj = ray.hitObject
hitpos = ray.hitPosition
hitnorm = ray.hitNormal

pos_vec = Vector(ray.hitPosition)
norm_vec = Vector(ray.hitNormal)*2
if lm:
    cube = scn.addObject("Cube1", hitobj, 0)
    cube.worldPosition = hitobj.worldPosition
cur.worldPosition = norm_vec
```

[image: level editor]

In the picture above I can not build any more than that.
Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the blend file, so that we can actually give it a try and see what's going wrong?

Comment: You might find [this useful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzR1hmkdxOQ)

Comment: Okay here's the link for it https://www.dropbox.com/s/cps8rb45mwt61pc/untitled.blend?dl=0

Comment: well that's almost what im looking for but he has his go to preset points i'm trying to get the object normal's but thanks c:.

Answer (score 1):

add a 'Filter' in each cube, that is the localized hit point for 'Buildible' faces,

then use .hitPosition and localize it, (this is using a rayCast)

```
    offset= Vector([5,0,0])
    offset = own.worldPosition+(own.worldOrientation*offset)
    Ray = own.rayCast(offset,own.worldPosition,0,'',1,1,0)
    ## attempting to localize hit point to hit object Ray[0]=hitObject
    ## Ray[1]=HitPosition
    Diff = Ray[0].worldPosition-Ray[1]
    Diff = Ray[0].worldOrientation.inverted()*Diff
    ## this will be used to then check to see if this type of part
    ## can go at this location and that the jack in unoccupied and 
    ## that the unit the part is hooking to is friendly
    Diff*=-1
    own['localHit']=str(Diff)
```

this is then used to check against hit jacks and put the block there, so you can build on a grid, but also you can define other setups like grid size vs block